Menu Items Toast not working in Android App Toolbar
I'm working in Android Studio java project.Just wanted to create a menu item on the toolbar.But after running the project , I don't see the TOAST view is working.Please help.enter image description here
This is the activity_main.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/firstRowLinearLayout"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/secondRowLinearLayout"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/thirdRowLinearLayout"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            >

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/question_text"
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestionNumber"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_value"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        >

    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgAnimal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_value"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_value_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_value_right"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtAnswer"
        android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_value"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="@dimen/answer_font_size"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        >

    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>



**
This is the menu xml that I have created and named as 'main_menu.xml' and created an item inside this called 'new_setings': ** **
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_build_24"
        android:title="settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    


</menu>

The java code in mainactivity:

package com.example.dontknow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
//        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
//        return true;
//    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id==R.id.new_settings){
           Toast.makeText(this, "clicked dfsssssssssssssssss ewrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }else {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing has happend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }










    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    //    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }






        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




















        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}


You need to call setContentView before setting up the toolbar.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
This code is already there at just a little bit down.Rewriting the way you suggested doesn't change anything.

Problem is solved.
This code was actually missing in activity_main.xml inside Toolbar :
app:menu="@menu/main_menu"

Needed to create a custom item style in the main_menu.xml for changing menu icons
I have inserted these codes for the icons otherwise only changing the drawables icons inside 'item' won't help.
style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
     <item name="android:src">@drawable/baseline_build_24</item>
 </style>

and added the new item of this MyTheme inside the parent application theme
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme</item>

